# Saving COG with NaN values using Python and GDAL

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have a numpy array (`data`) with some NaN values which I would like to save as a COG using GDAL. I am saving it first to GDAL memory layer and then to COG and I tired using both `CreateCopy`and `Translate` as shown below:

```
# Save to memory 
memDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName("MEM")
shape = data.shape
ds = memDriver.Create("MEM", shape[1], shape[0], 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
ds.SetProjection(proj)
ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)
band.WriteArray(data)

# Save to COG
fileFormat = "COG"
driverOpt = []
#driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(fileFormat)
#out_ds = driver.CreateCopy(outPath, ds, True, driverOpt)
out_ds = gdal.Translate(outPath, ds, format=fileFormat, creationOptions=driverOpt,
                        noData=noDataValue, stats=True, outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32)
out_ds = None
```

When I open the resulting file in QGIS I can see that the NaN value is not ignored when creating pyramids because the gaps expand as I zoom out until the whole image disappears (all pixels have no data value). See the images below. This is the same regardless of whether I use `CreateCopy` or `Translate`.

Is the method incorrect or is there some limitation/bug in GDAL COG driver?

I am using Python 3.8.8 and GDAL 3.1.4

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is "COG" ?

Comment: COG stands for Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/cog.html. Does gdalinfo show NaN as the nodata value?

Comment: is NaN a valid nodata value?

Comment: Seems to be `gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot float32 -a_nodata nan test.tif nan.tif` and then gdalinfo shows `Band 1 Block=1024x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Red  NoData Value=nan`. Trial to assign nodata `nap` leads into `NoData Value=0`

Comment: gdalinfo prints:
    `Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
    NoData Value=nan
    Overviews: 3423x2163, 1712x1082, 856x541, 428x271`.
Also if I change `fileFormat` from COG to GTiff then everything displays fine

Comment: How did you create the overviews in your GTiff test?

Comment: I did not use overviews when saving as GTiff. This test was just to show that NaN is a valid no-data value and can be handled by both GDAL and QGIS.

Comment: Ok. Continue your test by creating overviews for this plain tiff with gdaladdo and observe if nodata is spreading in the same way than with COG. Use gdaladdo with -ro for creating externals overviews, they are simple to delete before making the next test with new settings. The COG driver, or generator, creates the overviews by the same with its default settings.

Comment: I tried `gdalddo -ro` with different resampling algorithms (nearest, average and bilinear) and in all cases overviews are displayed fine in QGIS. For some reason `gdalddo` (without -ro) prints "done" but never returns. I also tried using tiff with external overviews as input to COG creation (with OVERVIEWS=FORCE_USE_EXISTING) but the overviews were not picked up.

Comment: Sorry, that last statement is incorrect. Using `gdal.Translate` with tiff with external overviews as input and COG as output works fine and the overviews are picked up and display fine. So this could be a workaround. Except that I cannot see equivalent to `gdalddo` in https://gdal.org/python/.

Comment: What I do is to set all NaNs to a known No Data value e.g. `data[np.isnan(data)]=NO_DATA_VALUE`